# Complex SQL Query (sum entries)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am wondering if something like this could be implemented in SQL query.

Let say I have these tables:

Table Orders

```
id tax 
01 800 
02 255
```

Table DetailOrders

```
id price itemName
01 700   Book
01 500   Umbrella
01 100   Jacket
02 1000  Piano
```

Basically single entry of one table Orders corresponds to multiple entries in DetailOrders.

Is there are any way to write SQL query that would return something like this:

```
id tax sum-price all-names
01 800   1300    Book, Umbrella, Jacket
02 255   1000    Piano
```

It would sum the price of items with the same id, and somehow merge the names of the items with same id.

Could something like this be achieved?

Comment: "Could something like this be achieved?" Yes, it could. Your turn now: could you show us what you have *tried* so far?

Comment: Take a look to the `group_concat()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  o.id,
        o.tax,
        sum(od.price) sum_price,
        group_concat(itemName) all_names
FROM    Orders o INNER JOIN
        DetailOrders do ON o.id = do.id
GROUP BY o.id,
         o.tax
```

Have a look at [GROUP_CONCAT(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL
>   values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't hard:

```
select
    o.id, o.tax,
    sum(d.price),
    group_concat(d.itemName)
from
    orders as o
    inner join detailOrders as d on o.id = d.id
group by
    o.id
```